# input onchange in for loop changing the last variable in loop?

Tags: javascript, function, dom, onchange

hello everyone I'm relatively new to javascript and I'm trying to use an input range with an onchange event but I make them in a loop from information that I get from the database sort of like this

```
var splitstring = response.split(String.fromCharCode(30));
for (var i = 0; i < splitstring.length; i++) {
  type = details[0];
  actualId = details[1];
  userId = details[2];
  time = details[3];
  //that's user details or whatever so i make the H2 and the range   


  var range = document.createElement("INPUT");
  var spanchange = document.createElement("H2");
  spanchange.appendChild(document.createTextNode("0 - neutral"));
  spanchange.style.cssFloat = "right";
  range.setAttribute("type", "range");
  range.setAttribute("class", "horizontal-lowest-first");
  range.setAttribute("min", "-100");
  range.setAttribute("value", "0");
  range.setAttribute("name", "range");
  var change = function() { ///range onchange to php :)
    var ranges = spanchange;
    var x = this.value;
    var then = x;

    if (x < -90) {
      then = x + " : " + "Extremely Poor";
    } else if (x < -80) {
      then = x + " : " + "Very Poor";
    } else if (x < -70) {
      then = x + " : " + "Pretty Bad";
    } else if (x < -60) {
      then = x + " : " + "Bad";
    } else if (x < -50) {
      then = x + " : " + "Not Good";
    } else if (x < -40) {
      then = x + " : " + "Phhhhst";
    } else if (x < -30) {
      then = x + " : " + "Oh No!";
    } else if (x < -20) {
      then = x + " : " + "Needs Work";
    } else if (x < -20) {
      then = x + " : " + "Crap";
    } else if (x < -10) {
      then = x + " : " + "Welp";
    } else if (x < 0) {
      then = x + " : " + "Downvote";
    } else if (x == 0) {
      then = x + " : " + "Neutral";
    } else if (x < 10) {
      then = x + " : " + "OH";
    } else if (x < 20) {
      then = x + " : " + "Better";
    } else if (x < 30) {
      then = x + " : " + "Yay";
    } else if (x < 40) {
      then = x + " : " + "Pretty Good";
    } else if (x < 50) {
      then = x + " : " + "Mediocre";
    } else if (x < 60) {
      then = x + " : " + "Great";
    } else if (x < 70) {
      then = x + " : " + "Yes!";
    } else if (x < 80) {
      then = x + " : " + "Awesome";
    } else if (x < 90) {
      then = x + " : " + "Very Good";
    } else if (x < 100) {
      then = x + " : " + "Top Grade";
    } else if (x == 100) {
      then = x + " : " + "Perfect!!";
    }
    console.log("inside onchange" + "    " + then);
    // var x = spanchange.childNodes[0];
    // x.replaceData(0, 20,then);
    ranges.innerHTML = then;
  };
  range.onchange = change;
}
```

then it adds the elements to a div and appends the div to the body then goes through the loop again
so in the function for onchange where i put

```
ranges.innerHTML = then;
```

it always changes the spanchange in the last for loops iteration so i mean if i change the first appended range, it sets the value of the last appended spanchange but i want it to change the spanchange that was in the same iteration of the for loop as that range, it sounds nuts i know I'm trying to explain, i hope someone can understand

if you can give me any advice id greatly appreciate it thank you

Comment: onchange gets called as a result of an event - the value of `spanchange` is probably not what you expect

Comment: right so is there a way to make the onchange function of that iteration reference the spanchange of the same iteration

Comment: the phrase you want to look for is `closure` - see https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/480/scope/1575/closures#t=201608230137057748783

Comment: i tried to do a closure example that ive seen on stackoverflow but i couldn't get it to work it would just fire the onchange once it loaded and then it wouldn't fire the onchange again, that was putting parameters into the function, I'm pretty stuck on this

Comment: Looks like the [infamous JS loop issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue) to me. (By the way, would it have killed you to format your code with sensible indenting before posting?)

Comment: ahhhh, i figured it out, thanks for direction, sorry about the formatting, thanks again